# Java HashSet object adding

Tags: java

I am trying to go through a text from a file, get each Word and save it as a Word object in a HashSet but i am alway getting the size 1 for the HashSet,it stores only the first object, i dont know maybe there is some really easy way to do it, or maybe i have made some stupid mistake here are you the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Taner\\Desktop\\words.txt");       
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    HashSet<Word> wordHash = new HashSet<>();

     while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = input.nextLine();      
         for (String retval: line.split(" ", 0)){
             wordTree.add(new Word(retval));
         } 
     }
     input.close();
     System.out.println(wordTree);
}
```

Comment: You can debug this more easily by removing both of your loops, and just adding two literals, e.g. `wordTree.add(new Word("hello")); wordTree.add(new Word("world"));`. If that works as expected, it is a problem with reading the data from the file; if it doesn't, it is a problem with the implementation of Word.

Comment: @AndyTurner thank u so much , i will try it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if `Word` has a broken implementation of `hashCode` and `equals`:
it would seem that all the values added in the `HashSet` are the same.
Check the implementations of those methods in `Word`.

If you use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ,
it can generate correct implementations for `hashCode` and `equals`.
I suggest you use that.

Comment: thank you so much @Janos i noticed that the equals method is not correctly coded :)